# Need help to fix this jQuery code snippet

Tags: jquery

I found this very useful code somewhere on this site:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

However, I'd prefer to identify my checkboxes by their classes rather than by their names, so I tried changing the snippet to this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[class="' + this.class + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

But that doesn't work, for some reason. I pretty sure I'm making a very rudimentary mistake, but if you could help me out that'd be great.

Comment: [https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+access+the+class+of+an+html+element+in+javascript](https://www.google.de/search?q=how+do+I+access+the+class+of+an+html+element+in+javascript&gws_rd=cr&ei=ebgZWdqJKcGpsAGImaz4Bw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the class from your input, use jQuery `attr` and asign to a variable:

[jQuery Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

As [stated by e_i_pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981793/need-help-to-fix-this-jquery-code-snippet/43982120?noredirect=1#comment75015931_43982120) in the comments, using `var class` is a little safer as it restricts the scope of the variable class to the function it is defined in.

```
var class = $(this).attr('class');
```

All together:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var class = $(this).attr('class');
    $('input.' + class).not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked after I gave it a small tweak (I changed "class" to "className").

Comment: @N.O. you asked for jQuery, that's why I wrote the jQuery selector
 ´attr('class')´, but also works if you use the DOM className property from JavaScript. As long as it helped and you got it to work, that's what matters :)

Comment: FYI `var class = $(this).attr('class');` is a little safer as it restricts the scope of the variable `class` to the function it is defined in.

Comment: Thnaks @e_i_pi ! It's good to be always learning something :)

Answer (score 0):

`element.class` is not a valid DOM property:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test').class);
```

```html
<div id="test" class="foo"></div>
```

You have to use `element.className` instead:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test').className);
```

```html
<div id="test" class="foo"></div>
```